# How to keep track of the language the user selected

Tags: internationalization

What is the best way to keep track of the language a user selected ?

a) storing the language setting in a session variable or cookie

b) reading the preferred language (locale) from the HTTP headers the browser sends

c) appending the language to the URL of every link in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d) Store the regional preferences into the user profile.

Of course this would require the whole burden of having profiles and passwords, but this is the best in context of web applications.

That also means that you should offer your log-in page based on the contents of HTTP Accept-Language header, then use the whatever language the user selected in the profile. The regional preferences page should default to the first supported language from the Accept-Language list (so that user may skip selection if it is already OK.)

If you still have doubts that this is the best option, please keep in mind that in the regional preferences page you may store a whole bunch of information such as:

- Preferred language (this is what you are asking for)
- The country that user lives in
- Preferred regional formats (things like date, time and numbers)
- The time zone
- Preferred writing system (aka script, i.e. Cyrillic vs. Latin)
- Measurement system (metric vs. imperial)
- Preferred encoding and the format of email messages (text vs. HTML)

Many of these things are simply undetectable or hardly detectable, because web browsers do not send these information. And you have the flexibility of adding more preferences responding to user's requests (i.e. some users may prefer 24 hour time format to 12 hour time format.)

In such case, what you would need to track would be the user session. You may put these preferences to the user session object, so that it will be easily available for any Locale-sensitive class.

Answer (score 0):

B & C

First read the preferred language from the browser headers, then redirect to the appropriate URL.

This way the same URL will not have different contents and confuse users and search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following:

All three options.

For new users read the locale out of the headers and write it into a cookie.
If the user changes his preferred language you can simply change it in the cookie and redirect to the wanted site.

If you just use B & C users won't be able to change their preferred language 
(at least it wouldn't be stored anywhere so they would have to change it on every visit)